# DIY Beginner's DC Power Supply?

Tags: power-supply, dc, safety

My school uses HY 3005D-3 but I want to do it myself to save on $. Before opening it, I ask for tips about: not-to-break-it, cheap DC supply and DIY-materials (not that I know them soon). So how to build, to get cheap DC Power supply with such adjusting knobs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before I got a real powersupply I used different kind of AC/DC or AC/AC power adapters, the kind that ship with toys, mobile phones, routers etc etc...

Then I just cut the cord and measured the voltage with a multimeter, and if needed added a simple linear regulator like the 7805 (if I wanted a clean 5V).

Comment: Apparently, 7805CWs are not explosive. Got it dirty hot even with 6A and about 5V. Just connected the outermost legs to catode and anode in the DC power-supply. Where do I need the middle leg?

Comment: ... time to finish my explosion chamber :)

Comment: 6A = Big heatsink... or spread the load over more than one power supply?

Comment: Is 7805CW a type of 7805? I wasn't able to find anything on the CW on google. I find it hard to believe that you are getting 6A and 5V. First of all, the middle lead on 7805s is a ground lead. I wouldn't think you would get much output without connecting this lead. Also, most 7805's that I have worked with start to drop their voltage after going over 1-1.5amps.

Comment: Personally I usually don't use 7805 (and the others) for bigger loads than 0.5A. But if you have a small design like a mcu that just needs 5V to run...

Comment: @Johan: could yo clarify how you get smooth DC? I have 7805reg, 12AC adaptor, 2 pieces of 100\muF caps, 1kOhms' resistors. Caps connected to the legs of reg, Rs connected to legs of caps. The voltage fluctuate, not greatly but still in range 4.81-4.86, the graph is more like sinusoidal. Do I need diodes to smooth it or sthing wrong?

Comment: You must send DC into the 7805, so you need to rectify your AC with 4 diods and another capacitor.

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a3/RC_Filter.png

Comment: I've been keeping an eye out for 5V and 12V (especially >=1A) wall warts on flea markets and other random places for a long time. They can be very handy, just need a suitable set of plugs/adaptors so you can go to pin headers, breadboard and/or banana plugs.

Comment: Your local thrift store carries these, usually $1 each. Assuming you have time to dig through the box.

Answer (score 5):

Are you wanting a DC power supply for one specific purpose, or want a generic power supply that will do everything that the one you mention does?

You can fairly cheaply buy an AC/DC transformer that will give you something like 12v dc and then you can use a voltage regulator with an adjustable voltage.

If you want it to do everything, ie have 3 variable voltages each with variable currents along with meters that show what the voltage and current usage are, then I would recommend just buying a power supply. You will find that building your own power supply is much more complicated then you are probably expecting.

Answer (score 5):

Why not get one of these kits: https://littlebirdelectronics.com.au/sparkfun-benchtop-power-board-kit and use with an old computer power supply? Then spend some time learning about power supply design, linear regulators, smoothing and so on.

Comment: That looks pretty cool. However, as a warning to the person who asked the question, computer power supplies are great at pumping out a lot of current, but not so great at being low noise. You will learn have to learn fast how to reduce noise on your power lines.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Hopefully the OP is productively studying and not just trying to 'explode' components :)

Comment: There's also an Instructable on DIY'ing this. You have to be competent enough to open the PS and fiddle with the insides, of course. 115VAC and big capacitors.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at [this kit from tuxgraphics](http://tuxgraphics.org/electronics/201005/bench-power-supply-v3.shtml).

It may not have all the features yon want, but for a DIY power supply, it may be a good start.